# UDP Socket reading last incoming byte

Tags: c++, sockets, udp

I have a socket which is sending a massiv among of byte, is often repeating the same information, but the receiver couldn't get all this bytes in a time. I had a way to slow down the sender side but now I have latencies, due that not enough bytes are coming. I need a real time transfer.

Is there a way that the receiver read the last incoming byte and discard the other ones then pursue in the program?

```
while (sock->isConnect() && tcpsock->isConnect()) {
    // with while instead of if, stuck in the loop
    if (sock->RecData(buff, 14)) { //receiving 14 bytes from UDP
        sendAngles2(buff);
        logger->setLatenz(logger->RECV);
    }
    logger->setLatenz(logger->MAIN);
    logger->LogData();
    // rest of the code 
}
```

Comment: Is this running in a dedicated thread, or as part of a larger main loop?

Comment: no this loop is in main() the largest loop

Comment: UDP is a stream not a block protocol.  You have to read all the bytes in order they arrive to get to the one(s) you want.

Comment: Silly question but... is each datagram sent *always* 14 bytes in size?

Comment: @RichardCritten UDP is *not* a stream protocol. UDP is a datagram protocol which means you get individual messages. There are no guarantees about ordering or reliability. You receive an entire message or no message at all. TCP on the other hand, is a stream protocol.

Comment: @Yann Are you sure you are wanting/using a UDP socket? Your code includes `sock->isConnect()` which doesn't make sense for a UDP socket because the UDP protocol is connectionless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortuntely, there's no standard/normal way of doing this <sup>1</sup> -- when a new packet is received for a UDP socket that has a full receive buffer, the new packet is dropped, even when it would be preferrable to drop the older (buffered) packets.

One thing you can do is use `setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RECVBUF,`... to crank down the size of the socket receive buffer.  Doing this will cause it to start dropping packets sooner when the receiver falls behind, paradoxically reducing the latency in processing packets, similar to [bufferbloat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bufferbloat) mitigation techniques.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>there's no way to do this on Linux or BSD of which I'm aware; some real-time OSes may have a way of doing it</sub>

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way that the receiver read the last incoming byte and discard the other ones then pursue in the program?

Yes. Set the socket non-blocking. If necessary, use `select` to wait for data to arrive if you need to do that.

Then keep calling `recv` (or `recvfrom`) in a loop until it returns a `EWOULDBLOCK` error. Then use the data you received from the previous call (make sure to save its length).

Comment: Or he could loop while `recv()` with the MSG_PEEK option returns > 0, and read inside the loop, but of course that would double the system calls.

Comment: @user207421 That does not work. This is UDP and UDP datagrams can be discarded. So his last read could block if the datagram was discarded after his `recv(MSG_PEEG)` and before his final `recv`. Some real platforms actually do this! (For example, if checksums are globally disabled and a datagram with a bad checksum is received and then checksums are enabled between the two `recv` calls. It is an error to use a status-reporting function as if it provided a future guarantee. They just don't do that.)