# Python socket stop queuing

Tags: python, sockets, udp

A program not made by me is sending coordinates using a python UDP socket.
I am able to process and receive the data, but there is a problem. My program is lagging behind from the tag that transmits the data more and more as time passes. I assume that some kind of queuing is happening because my program is to slow, as my current solution is to process one coordinate and then just quickly read a bunch more to keep up to date before processing again. While this works I don't like this solution, should it not be possible to take some kind of LIFO approach and then flush the remaining data after having read the latest coordinates? Attached is a snippet of my code, some of the processes that takes a long time have been removed.

```
def main():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    adress = ("IP",PORT)
    sock.bind(adress)
    while True:
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
        split_by_letter = re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', data.decode('ascii'))
        final_coord = str(split_by_letter)[3:-2]
```

Comment: If you need only the latest coordinates, you can run the `recv()` in a separate thread and let that update a common variable which you can access to get latest value. while taking care of concurrency

Comment: You are right, it is sort of the same solution like the one I have, but a bit more consistent. I just think it is insane that I have to allocate an entire thread to do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UDP Socket reading last incoming byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45761475/udp-socket-reading-last-incoming-byte)

Comment: Well it might, the answer there is no, but it is 3 years old and about C++. But it is also from one of the answers I got my current approach.